# Understanding javap's output for the Constant Pool

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javap

When running javap on a very simple HelloWorld application I have some confusion on the output around the constant pool.

**Test Code**

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

**Javap -c -verbose output (snipped)**

```
// Header + consts 1..22 snipped
const #22 = String      #23;    //  hello world
const #23 = Asciz       hello world;

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   getstatic       #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3:   ldc     #22; //String hello world
   5:   invokevirtual   #24; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   8:   return
  // Debug info snipped
}
```

Ok, so on line 3 we see a pushing of the "hello world" constant onto the stack via #22, but const #23 seems to hold the actual value. I guess I am a little confused with what the #(number) means when it appears on the right-hand-side of the printout.

[Oracle/Sun's man page for javap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All your `class`, `interface`, `field` names and `string` constants go into the java **constant pool**.

As per VM Spec ( http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html ):

> The constant_pool is a table of
>   structures (§4.4) representing various
>   string constants, class and interface
>   names, field names, and other
>   constants that are referred to within
>   the ClassFile structure and its
>   substructures. The format of each
>   constant_pool table entry is indicated
>   by its first "tag" byte. The
>   constant_pool table is indexed from 1
>   to constant_pool_count-1.

So in terms of constant pool something like below can be viewed as:

```
const #22 = String      #23;    //  hello world
const #23 = Asciz       hello world;
```

The value at #22 (index 22) is of type `String` and its value is null terminated c string ([Asciz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string)) `hello world` is at index 23.

Comment: as of `jdk-7` (http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6868539) it's `utf8` and not `asciz`

Answer (score 5):

The Java constant pool stores two different kinds of entries when storing a string.  First, it stores the string literal as UTF-8 encoded data (here, constant #23).  Second, it also stores an string entry (#22) indicating that the contents of constant #23 should be used to construct a `String`.  I think the reason for this is that the JVM associates with each class a "runtime constant pool" consisting of a dynamic implementation of the given constants.  For strings, this can be a reference to the interned `String` object holding the given characters.  UTF-8 constant data has other uses besides string literals (for example, naming fields and classes), so this extra indirection seems like a reasonable way to separate out the concerns.

Answer (score 4):

Pool entry #22 is a java.lang.String object. Entry #23 is the array of characters used to construct that String.

The [Java VM Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) is the "missing manual" for javap.