# Is String Literal Pool a collection of references to the String Object, Or a collection of Objects

Tags: java, string, memory-management

I am all confused after reading the article on javaranch site by Corey McGlone, The author of  The SCJP Tip Line. named Strings, Literally and the
SCJP Java 6 Programmer Guide by Kathy Sierra (co-founder of javaranch) and Bert Bates.

I will try to quote what Mr. Corey and Ms Kathy Sierra have quoted about String Literal Pool.

**1.** According to Mr Corey McGlone :

- String Literal Pool is a Collection of references that point to the String Objects.
- `String s = "Hello";`  (Assume there is No object on the Heap named "Hello"), 
    will create a String object `"Hello"` on the heap, and will place a reference to this object in the String Literal Pool (Constant Table)
- `String a = new String("Bye");` (Assume there is No object on the Heap named "Bye", `new` operator will oblige the JVM to create an object on the Heap.

Now the explanation of  `"new"` operator for the creation of a String and its reference is bit confusing in this article, so I am putting the code and
    explanation from the article itself as it-is below.

```
public class ImmutableStrings
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String one = "someString";
        String two = new String("someString");

        System.out.println(one.equals(two));
        System.out.println(one == two);
    }
}
```

In this case, we actually end up with a slightly different behavior because of the keyword `"new."` 
In such a case, references to the two String literals are still put into the constant table (the String Literal Pool),
but, when you come to the keyword `"new,"` the JVM is obliged to create a new String object at run-time, 
rather than using the one from the constant table.

Here is the diagram explaining it..

[image]

**So does it mean, that String Literal Pool too has a reference to this Object ?**

Here is the link to the Article by Corey McGlone

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/Journal200409.jsp#a1

**2.** According to Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates in SCJP book:

- To make Java more memory efficient, the JVM set aside a special area of memory called the "String constant pool", when the compiler
  encounters a String Literal, it checks the pool to see if an identical String already exists or not. If not then it creates a 
  new String Literal Object.
- `String s = "abc";`  // Creates one String object and one reference variable....

  that's fine, but then I was confused by this statement:
- `String s = new String("abc")` // Creates two objects, and one reference variable.

  It says in the book that.... a new String object in normal(non-pool) memory , and "s" will refer to it... whereas
  an additional literal "abc" will be placed in the pool.

  The above lines in the book collide with the one in the article by Corey McGlone.

  - If String Literal Pool is a collection of references to the String object as mentioned by Corey McGlone, then why wil the literal object "abc" be placed in the pool (as mentioned in the book)?
  - And where does this String Literal Pool reside?

Please clear this doubt, though it won't matter too much while writing a code, but is very important from the aspect of memory management, and
thats the reason I want to clear this funda.

Comment: How the pool is managed might to some degree depend on the JVM implementation. As long as something isn't fixed by the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5), they are free to experiment. So whether the pool holds references or objects might well depend, I believe.

Comment: I recently came across exact same question with same 2 resources you mentioned. I think by statement **object "abc" will be placed in the pool** in book, author means reference to object "abc" will be stored in pool. Right? Accepted answer is pretty informative but I think this is what being asked.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I think the main point to understand here is the distinction between `String` Java object and its contents - `char[]` under [private `value` field](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.0value). `String` is basically a wrapper around `char[]` array, encapsulating it and making it impossible to modify so the `String` can remain immutable. Also the `String` class remembers which parts of this array is actually used (see below). This all means that you can have two different `String` objects (quite lightweight) pointing to the same `char[]`.

I will show you few examples, together with `hashCode()` of each `String` and `hashCode()` of internal `char[] value` field (I will call it *text* to distinguish it from string). Finally I'll show `javap -c -verbose` output, together with constant pool for my test class. Please do not confuse class constant pool with string literal pool. They are not quite the same. See also [Understanding javap's output for the Constant Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546280).

## *Prerequisites*

For the purpose of testing I created such a utility method that breaks `String` encapsulation:

```
private int showInternalCharArrayHashCode(String s) {
    final Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    value.setAccessible(true);
    return value.get(s).hashCode();
}
```

It will print `hashCode()` of `char[] value`, effectively helping us understand whether this particular `String` points to the same `char[]` text or not.

## Two string literals in a class

Let's start from the simplest example.

### Java code

```
String one = "abc";
String two = "abc";
```

BTW if you simply write `"ab" + "c"`, Java compiler will perform concatenation at compile time and the generated code will be exactly the same. This only works if all strings are known at compile time.

### Class constant pool

Each class has its own [constant pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#The_constant_pool) - a list of constant values that can be reused if they occur several times in the source code. It includes common strings, numbers, method names, etc.

Here are the contents of the constant pool in our example above.

```
const #2 = String   #38;    //  abc
//...
const #38 = Asciz   abc;
```

The important thing to note is the distinction between `String` constant object (`#2`) and Unicode encoded text `"abc"` (`#38`) that the string points to.

### Byte code

Here is generated byte code. Note that both `one` and `two` references are assigned with the same `#2` constant pointing to `"abc"` string:

```
ldc #2; //String abc
astore_1    //one
ldc #2; //String abc
astore_2    //two
```

### Output

For each example I am printing the following values:

```
System.out.println(showInternalCharArrayHashCode(one));
System.out.println(showInternalCharArrayHashCode(two));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(one));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(two));
```

No surprise that both pairs are equal:

```
23583040
23583040
8918249
8918249
```

Which means that not only both objects point to the same `char[]` (the same text underneath) so `equals()` test will pass. But even more, `one` and `two` are the exact same references! So `one == two` is true as well. Obviously if `one` and `two` point to the same object then `one.value` and `two.value` must be equal.

## Literal and `new String()`

### Java code

Now the example we all waited for - one string literal and one new `String` using the same literal. How will this work?

```
String one = "abc";
String two = new String("abc");
```

The fact that `"abc"` constant is used two times in the source code should give you some hint...

### Class constant pool

Same as above.

### Byte code

```
ldc #2; //String abc
astore_1    //one

new #3; //class java/lang/String
dup
ldc #2; //String abc
invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
astore_2    //two
```

Look carefully! The first object is created the same way as above, no surprise. It just takes a constant reference to already created `String` (`#2`) from the constant pool. However the second object is created via normal constructor call. But! The first `String` is passed as an argument. This can be decompiled to:

```
String two = new String(one);
```

### Output

The output is a bit surprising. The second pair, representing references to `String` object is understandable - we created two `String` objects - one was created for us in the constant pool and the second one was created manually for `two`. But why, on earth the first pair suggests that both `String` objects point to the same `char[] value` array?!

```
41771
41771
8388097
16585653
```

It becomes clear when you look at how [`String(String)` constructor works](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) (greatly simplified here):

```
public String(String original) {
    this.offset = original.offset;
    this.count = original.count;
    this.value = original.value;
}
```

See? When you are creating new `String` object based on existing one, it **reuses** `char[] value`. `String`s are immutable, there is no need to copy data structure that is known to be never modified.

I think this is the clue of your problem: even if you have two `String` objects, they might still point to the same contents. And as you can see the `String` object itself is quite small.

## Runtime modification and `intern()`

### Java code

Let's say you initially used two different strings but after some modifications they are all the same:

```
String one = "abc";
String two = "?abc".substring(1);  //also two = "abc"
```

The Java compiler (at least mine) is not clever enough to perform such operation at compile time, have a look:

### Class constant pool

Suddenly we ended up with two constant strings pointing to two different constant texts:

```
const #2 = String   #44;    //  abc
const #3 = String   #45;    //  ?abc
const #44 = Asciz   abc;
const #45 = Asciz   ?abc;
```

### Byte code

```
ldc #2; //String abc
astore_1    //one

ldc #3; //String ?abc
iconst_1
invokevirtual   #4; //Method String.substring:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
astore_2    //two
```

The fist string is constructed as usual. The second is created by first loading the constant `"?abc"` string and then calling `substring(1)` on it.

### Output

No surprise here - we have two different strings, pointing to two different `char[]` texts in memory:

```
27379847
7615385
8388097
16585653
```

Well, the texts aren't really *different*, `equals()` method will still yield `true`. We have two unnecessary copies of the same text.

Now we should run two exercises. First, try running:

```
two = two.intern();
```

before printing hash codes. Not only both `one` and `two` point to the same text, but they are the same reference!

```
11108810
11108810
15184449
15184449
```

This means both `one.equals(two)` and `one == two` tests will pass. Also we saved some memory because `"abc"` text appears only once in memory (the second copy will be garbage collected).

The second exercise is slightly different, check out this:

```
String one = "abc";
String two = "abc".substring(1);
```

Obviously `one` and `two` are two different objects, pointing to two different texts. But how come the output suggests that they both point to the same `char[]` array?!?

```
23583040
23583040
11108810
8918249
```

I'll leave the answer to you. It'll teach you how `substring()` works, what are the advantages of such approach and when it can [lead to big troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281549).

Comment: +1 , thanks for giving an in-depth working knowledge of String. But The above presented info is something i already had an idea about.. My question still stands... do the String Literal Pool is an Collection of Objects or Reference... And if String Literal Pool Holds object, so will using new operator will create two String objects, one outside and one inside the Memory Pool, and the reference points to the one outside Memory Pool.

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra: the exact details are probably implementation dependant. For sure string literals [are placed in PermGen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918399) - but whether these are barely references to *normal* heap or char arrays themselves are also in PermGen - hard to say. Also check out references at the bottom of [Java Constant Pool : String
 ](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2007/08/10/java-constant-pool-string/) article.

Comment: Great and in-depth answer Tomasz! Good to see some bytecode examples as it reveals some of the magic that happens under the hood. +1 mate!

Comment: +1 brilliant answer. But I think in the last example's output, you are getting similar hashCode for the String object not the vlaue char array.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: +1, you are right, thanks! The output as it was had no sense

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz  aswm answer . +1 to the patience and indepth explanation

Comment: **Is String Literal Pool a collection of references to the String Object, Or a collection of Objects** ,but what is the exactly answer?

Comment: As of Java 7, substring creates a new copy of the part of the array that is required and does not point to the same one.

Comment: This answer does not provide an answer to the initial question. What does String Pool look like internally? Is it a collection of references or a collection of strings?