# String Immutable in Java

Tags: java, string

I wanted to ask about String and Reference
variable,
String name = "John"
String str= "John"
In the video it says that it will refer to the value
"John" instead of creating another value "John". If
this was the case then if we compare (name == str) why would it give False? Does variable name
and Str refer to the same address in the Heap?

Comment: Please show the code you executed that shows this behavior.

Comment: Try reading these answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/217324

Comment: "why would it give False?" It would not give `false`. Show the code demonstrating that it gives `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It is called String interning. If the constant (in this case "John") is a [compile time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973722/determine-whether-a-string-is-a-compile-time-constant), then the compiler will use "John".intern() when compiling and it will go to the string "pool"  hence the 2 "interned" string reference will be the same therefore using "==" will return **true**. [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/jvms14.pdf) page 359:

> If the method String.intern has previously been invoked on an instance
> of
> class String containing a sequence of Unicode code points identical to that
> given by the CONSTANT_String_info structure, then the string constant is a
> reference to that same instance of class String

Answer (score -1):

The == operator is used for checking the reference of both the string objects in Java.

https://dzone.com/articles/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java (search for Problems Using the == Operator for String Comparison)