# String.intern() shows strange result, how does it work

Tags: java, string, jvm, intern, string-constant

I know that String.intern() adds string to pool if it does not contain the object, but how to explain the results.

The code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] abc = new char[]{'a','b','c'};
        String str = new String(abc);
        System.out.println(str == "abc");
        str.intern();
        System.out.println(str == "abc");
    }
```

output is :

false

false

However when code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] abc = new char[]{'a','b','c'};
        String str = new String(abc);
        str.intern();
        System.out.println(str == "abc");
    }
```

The output is:

true

What's the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that when you use the `String` literal "abc" before the explicit call to `intern`, it is implicitly interned.

`str.intern()` doesn't store the instance referenced by `str` in the String pool if an equal `String` is already in the pool.

First snippet:

```
System.out.println(str == "abc"); // "abc" is interned
str.intern(); // str is not stored in the pool
System.out.println(str == "abc"); // returns false
```

Second snippet:

```
str.intern(); // str is stored in the pool
System.out.println(str == "abc"); // returns true
```

From the Javadoc of intern:

> **String java.lang.String.intern()**
>
> When the intern method is invoked, **if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned**. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned...
> **All literal strings** and string-valued constant expressions **are interned**.

Comment: This difference has been used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929935/2711488) to detect whether a string already exists in the pool resp. when a string literal is resolved to a string object at runtime.