# Does String.intern has anything to to with JVM Run-Time Constant pool

Tags: java, string, jvm, pool

According to the `jvms11`, there are two kinds of entry in the run-time constant pool: symbolic references, which may later be resolved, and static constants, which require no further processing. The static constants in the run-time constant pool are also derived from entries in the constant_pool table in accordance with the structure of each entry.

My understanding is String.intern has nothing to to with JVM Run-Time Constant pool, but someone who is one of the greatest programmer in China said `String.intern` would *"put something in the Run-Time Constant pool during runtime"* in his popular book. We argued about this for a long time，we both can't convince each other.

So my question is, does String.intern has anything to to with JVM Run-Time Constant pool?

Here is the jvms5.1 about [Rum-Time Constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1)

Comment: No.  It has absolutely nothing to do with it.  But rather than arguing about it ... or asking for other peoples' input ... you should BOTH download the OpenJDK source code and look at the evidence.

Comment: The constant pool is not the same as the String poo (used by `intern()`)l, BUT they are somehow *related* **¹** as described by [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1-300-A-A) and the following point of the same section that you linked to (that is: before the class initialization is done, string entries in the constant pool will be the same as the corresponding one in the String pool) || **¹** "has anything to do" was the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JVMS §5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1) says

> The Java Virtual Machine maintains a run-time constant pool for each class and interface ([§2.5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.5)).

The term “for each” means that there is not one run-time constant pool, but each class or interface has its own dedicated pool. The subsequent sentences make even clear that this data structure corresponds to the constant pool of a class file.

> The `constant_pool` table in the binary representation of a class or interface ([§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4)) is used to construct the run-time constant pool upon class or interface creation ([§5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3)).

It should be clear that this per-class structure is not the same as the single global data structure used to canonicalize string instances throughout the entire runtime.

But since all uses of string constants in a class file are expressed as indices into the class file’s constant pool which is then used to construct the class’s run-time constant pool, there is a relationship between these uses and the global data structure. As stated [within §5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1-300)

> The static constants in the run-time constant pool are also derived from entries in the `constant_pool` table in accordance with the structure of each entry:
>
> - A string constant is a `reference` to an instance of class `String`, and is derived from a `CONSTANT_String_info` structure ([§4.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.3)). To derive a string constant, the Java Virtual Machine examines the sequence of code points given by the `CONSTANT_String_info` structure:
>
>   - If the method `String.intern` has previously been invoked on an instance of class `String` containing a sequence of Unicode code points identical to that given by the `CONSTANT_String_info` structure, then the string constant is a `reference` to that same instance of class `String`.
>   - Otherwise, a new instance of class `String` is created containing the sequence of Unicode code points given by the `CONSTANT_String_info` structure. The string constant is a `reference` to the new instance. Finally, the method `String.intern` is invoked on the new instance.

So formally, the `String` instances corresponding to the string constants used in a class are part of that class’s runtime constant pool but initialized in terms of `String.intern` to ensure that each class has canonicalized string instances in its pool.

But this relationship has only one direction. When application code invokes `String.intern()` explicitly, it won’t access a class’s run-time constant pool. It wouldn’t even be clear, which run-time constant pool we shall expect to be accessed.

*So `intern()` has nothing do to with the run-time constant pool, at least not more than it has to do with every other caller.*

A source of confusion is the fact that the data structure used by the JVM to implement `intern()` has no name in the JVMS or JLS at all. So, without a formal name, different names appear in different media. E.g., the [API documentation of `intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()) says

> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class `String`.

It’s typically some kind of hash table, but the term “pool” matches its purpose and since it exists at runtime, it’s not surprising that people come up with terms easy to confuse with the run-time constant pools of JVMS §5.1.

So before starting a heated discussion with another developer, it’s important to clarify, whether everyone is talking about the same pool.

---

As an addendum, I said above that the `String` is *formally* part of the run-time constant pool, as this hits implementation specific aspects.

In principle, a JVM could initialize all string entries of a class’s run-time constant pool with `String` instances when creating the pool. But as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929935/2711488) demonstrates, this is not the case for the widely used HotSpot JVM which looks up or creates a `String` instance on the first use rather than class initialization time.

This implies that the run-time constant pool contains the raw character data in some form instead of a reference to a `String` instance. Once the `String` is constructed, it is referenced and reused by the code, but whether the run-time constant pool is modified to reference the `String` now or the bytecode instruction (`ldc`) keeps it, is not observable from the Java application. All we can observe, is that the `String` instance does not get garbage collected as long as the class exist.