# String objects and storage

Tags: java, string, heap-memory, string-pool

How many objects will be created in the following code and where they will be stored?

```
String s = "abc"; // line 1
String s1 = new String("abc"); // line 2
String str1 = new String("efg"); //line 3
```

Comment: 3 objects will be created, 1 in SCP and two in heap

Comment: What would be your best guess and why?

Comment: Searching for `how many strings created` yields lots of similar questions.

Comment: @Deadpool Please excuse me but I don't speak [newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak) Does _SCP_ mean "String Constant Pool"?

Comment: @Abra You are more fluent than you thought. :)

Comment: yes i mean `String Constant Pool` @Abra

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672427/string-s-new-stringxyz-how-many-objects-has-been-made-after-this-line-of

Comment: won't "efg" will also be stored in String Pool ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Total 3 objects will be created.    
Line 1 : Object will be created in string pool,
Line 2 : Object will be created in Heap,
Line 3 : Object will be created in Heap.

Reason is : 
a) By string literal : Java String literal is created by using double quotes like in line 1. It is always created in String pool,
b) By new keyword : Java String is created by using a keyword “new” like in line 2 and 3.  It is always created in Heap memory.
```

For reference: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-initialization-java-string-literal-vs-string-object/